# Aligning subsetted data points with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a complex figure that overlays individual data points on a boxplot to display both summary statistics as well as dispersion of the raw data. I have 2 questions in rank order of importance:

1. How do I center the jittered points around the middle of their respective box plot?
2. How can I remove the dark dots from the "drv" legend?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mpg$cyl <- as.factor(mpg$cyl)

mpg %>% filter(fl=="p" | fl=="r" & cyl!="5") %>% sample_n(100) %>% ggplot(aes(cyl, hwy, fill=drv)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width=0.5, position = position_dodge(1)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(1), outlier.shape = NA)+
  geom_point(aes(fill=drv, shape=fl), color="black", show.legend=TRUE, alpha=0.5, size=3, position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 1)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,23))
```

[image: Example figure]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the current dodging for `geom_point` is based on both `fill` and `shape`.  Use `group` to indicate you only want to dodge on `drv`.

You can use `override.aes` in `guide_legend` to remove the points from the `fill` legend.

```
mpg %>%
    filter(fl=="p" | fl=="r" & cyl!="5") %>% 
    sample_n(100) %>%
    ggplot(aes(cyl, hwy, fill=drv)) +
      stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width=0.5, position = position_dodge(1)) +
      geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(1), outlier.shape = NA)+
      geom_point(aes(fill = drv, shape = fl, group = drv), color="black", 
                 alpha  =0.5, size=3, 
                 position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = .1, dodge.width = 1)) +
      scale_shape_manual (values = c(21,23) ) +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA) ) )
```

[image]